# Weird NullPointerException WebSocketHandshake.verifyServerHandshakeHeaders with google bundles

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, android-app-bundle

After i updated android studio 3.0->3.2 to start using google bundles apk i'm getting this weird error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase(java.util.Locale)' on a null object reference
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocketHandshake.verifyServerHandshakeHeaders(SourceFile:111)
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.runReader(SourceFile:418)
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket.access$000(SourceFile:47)
       at com.google.firebase.database.tubesock.WebSocket$2.run(SourceFile:143)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

THE WEIRD THING IS:

This error is registered between 30-50 times few seconds after I upload the apk bundle to google play (so it isn't available to download on play store yet)

100% of devices that register this error are:

```
Device
Brand: LGE
Model: Nexus 5X
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 3.19 GB
Disk free: 2.04 GB
Operating System
Version: 6.0.1
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted: Yes
```

And the error just happen these initial times after upload... on normal running situations nobody else gets

It seems like an error on google, but it is annoying because everytime i close when i have an app update it sends me an alert saying "error is back"

Does anyone know what is it? how to solve?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be Google Play testing your app for malware on some devices. This particular device seems to have something that triggers a bug in Firebase.